# Windows 8 app/thread

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows

I'm new to windows 8, still understanding the basics and how it works. My ultimate goal is to design an app/thread, which can be installed on a windows 8 tablet. This app/thread will have ip data and can kick start the rdp app installed locally on the tablet. Obviously, once this is done and the credentials are inputted, the remote session will start.

I know this may be slightly off topic, however can someone kindly point me in a direction, I've been 'googleling' for the past few days however my search returned with undesired results. The reason behind this is probably, I'm using the wrong keywords(coming from an android background) so any help is much appreciated. I would particularly like to know if there are any API's I can make use of.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Getting started:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229512.aspx

**Create your first app:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx

(Google search queries: *"how to windows 8 metro app"* and *"metro app tutorial"*)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your specific requirement, you're not going to be able to launch directly another process from a Windows Store application. With the sandboxed model the platform enforces, you'll typically use [file or protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

*As for "the basics and how it works", your best overall entry point for resources to build Windows Store Apps is [Generation App](http://aka.ms/8in30), offering a combination of technical resources and live consultations with experts.*